# Difference between session[:previous_url] and request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, session, http-referer

What is the difference between session[:previous_url] and request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] ?
I am getting `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "http://identity.service.consul:3000/identity/users/sign_in"`

whereas
`session[:previous_url] = "/identity/oauth/authorize?client_id=343a467ca6a39537c205bec97f9d6323245046eb1742fb13d0fec47f7266faea&redirect_uri=http://localhost:50083/portal/v2/login&response_type=code&state=03UTf8"`

request.env is giving me the immediated last where it got called, whereas session is giving the second last url. Can someone help ? I am new in this domain.

Comment: I believe session has a `current_url` that is effectively the last URL the user has visited - `previous_url` will be the address they visited before their current visit.

Comment: in case of sessoin I am getting previous to previous url, and not the immediate previous one.. and if previous_url of session is supposed to give the last url then HTTP_REFERER and session[:previous_url] should have the same value. Isnt it? But here I am getting different value.